# How to get Microsoft MPEG4 Source to open MOV with bitrate higher than 4Gbps

Tags: video, ms-media-foundation

It seems that when the bitrate of a MOV is too high and can't fit into 32-bits then the [Microsoft MPEG 4 Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/mpeg-4-file-source) won't parse it.  Does anyone know of a workaround for this behaviour?

I'm pretty sure it's related to the bitrate because I have generated test files and by tweaking only the frame rate I generated two files - the one with the bitrate over 4.2Gbps (32-bits) doesn't open, but the other with bitrate just less than 4.2Gps opens file.

I've tried opening the file with IMFSourceReader:

```
            IMFSourceReader* reader = nullptr;
            hr = MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL(L"input.mov", nullptr, &reader);
            SAFE_RELEASE(reader);
```

But this just returns E_FAIL.

I've tried opening it via IMFSourceResolver:

```
        IMFMediaSource* source = nullptr;

        IMFSourceResolver* resolver = nullptr;
        MFCreateSourceResolver(&resolver);

        MF_OBJECT_TYPE objectType;
        IUnknown* result = nullptr;
        hr = resolver->CreateObjectFromURL(L"input.mov", MF_RESOLUTION_MEDIASOURCE | MF_RESOLUTION_CONTENT_DOES_NOT_HAVE_TO_MATCH_EXTENSION_OR_MIME_TYPE | MF_RESOLUTION_READ, nullptr, &objectType, &result);
```

This fails too.

To reproduce this, I've uploaded a small [400KB ZIP](https://rh-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/media/MOV-Hap-4Gbps.zip) containing:

1. 3000x3000 source image
2. .bat ffmpeg command to generate the videos
3. a 3000x3000 @ 59fps HapQ MOV file - MPEG4 Source can resolve this, the bitrate is just less than 4.2Gbps
4. a 3000x3000 @ 60fps HapQ MOV file - MPEG4 Source can't resolve this, the bitrate is just mover 4.2Gbps

For reference here the videos are generated:

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i black3000.png -t 0.2 -r 59 -s 3000x3000 -c:v hap -format hap_q -compressor none output-good.mov
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i black3000.png -t 0.2 -r 60 -s 3000x3000 -c:v hap -format hap_q -compressor none output-bad.mov
pause
```

Had anyone else seen this behaviour before and know of a workaround?

Thanks,

Comment: If you activate MF traces, you'll see MF tries all byte stream handlers (IMFByteStreamHandler) it has and all (on my PC, thats MPEG4, ADTS, AC-3, MF AMRNB, ASF, AVI, WTV, MF FLAC, MPEG2, MKV, MP3, NSC, SAMI, WAV, LPCM) report MF_E_INVALID_FILE_FORMAT error. So, no byte stream handler supports that stream. To workaround you could try to add your own MFRegisterLocalByteStreamHandler.

Comment: Yes I've been using MFTrace - and for the good stream it IS able to find the handler - the MPEG 4 Source.  For the bad stream (too high bitrate) it indeed fails.

Comment: Actually, MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE is an UINT32 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/mf-mt-avg-bitrate-attribute  and in the good case trace you clearly see MPEG4 adds "MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE=4235297882". So I guess, the MPEG4 handler computes this and probably overflows. MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE is more an output thing, not sure what it's doing with it. You could try to wrap it with your own and register it using MFRegisterLocalByteStreamHandler.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean - okay I will try that and update if it works. (btw your magic number database is awesome, i've used it many times to find obscure GUIDS).

Comment: Thanks :-) Especially useful for all those MF's guids! For example, CLSID_MPEG4ByteStreamPlugin which is the MPEG4 Byte Stream Handler.

Comment: I started to implement a ByteStreamHandler, but then I realised I would have to get it to return the Microsoft MPEG4 Source - but I can't find how to do that.. I tried to instantiate an IClassFactory from CLSID_MPEG4ParserClassFactory and then tried to get interface for IMFMediaSource but it ddidn't have the interface...

Comment: The failing implementation is in parser of media source itself, not in byte stream handler, so customized byte stream would get you nothing. You need custom media source to work around faulty implementation of stock media source.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like as @Simon Mourier suggested, the only way to solve this would be to implement a custom ByteStreamHandler and register it with MFRegisterLocalByteStreamHandler, but you would ALSO have to create a custom IMFMediaSource, as I can't find any way to simply instantiate the MPEG4 Source as it seems you can only create it via its' ByteStreamHandler..

For reference, here is the pseudo test code I was using to create to manually create the MPEG4 source without using the Source Resolver:

```
#include <initguid.h>
DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_MPEG4ByteStreamPlugin, 0x271c3902, 0x6095, 0x4c45, 0xa2, 0x2f, 0x20, 0x09, 0x18, 0x16, 0xee, 0x9e);


class CallbackTest : public IMFAsyncCallback
{
public:
    CallbackTest(IMFByteStreamHandler* handler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
    }

    IMFByteStreamHandler* _handler;

    virtual HRESULT QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void ** ppvObject) override
    {
        return HRESULT();
    }
    virtual ULONG AddRef(void) override
    {
        return 1;
    }
    virtual ULONG Release(void) override
    {
        return 1;
    }
    virtual HRESULT GetParameters(DWORD * pdwFlags, DWORD * pdwQueue) override
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall Invoke(IMFAsyncResult * pAsyncResult) override
    {
        // At this point HR = E_FAIL for > 4.2Gbps MOV
        HRESULT hr = pAsyncResult->GetStatus();

        MF_OBJECT_TYPE objectType;
        IUnknown* unknownObject = nullptr;
        hr = _handler->EndCreateObject(pAsyncResult, &objectType, &unknownObject);

// NOTE: I also tried to just force creating the MPEG 4 Source by calling
// EndCreateObject with a dummy IMFAsyncResult but that always failed..

        IMFMediaSource* mediaSource = nullptr;
        hr = unknownObject->QueryInterface(&mediaSource);

        return S_OK;
    }
};

void Test()
{
    HRESULT hr;

    // Create a bytestream from the file
    IMFByteStream* byteStream = nullptr;
    hr = MFCreateFile(MF_ACCESSMODE_READ, MF_OPENMODE_FAIL_IF_NOT_EXIST, MF_FILEFLAGS_NOBUFFERING, fileUrl, &byteStream);

// Create the MPEG4 ByteStreamHandler
    IMFByteStreamHandler* handler = nullptr;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MPEG4ByteStreamPlugin, nullptr, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMFByteStreamHandler, (void**)&handler);
    
    IMFAsyncCallback* callback = new CallbackTest(handler);
    hr = handler->BeginCreateObject(byteStream, nullptr, MF_RESOLUTION_MEDIASOURCE | MF_RESOLUTION_READ | MF_RESOLUTION_CONTENT_DOES_NOT_HAVE_TO_MATCH_EXTENSION_OR_MIME_TYPE, nullptr, nullptr, callback, handler);
}
```